# Does "I would not recommend to my worst enemy" make sense?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Does "I would not recommend this place to my worst enemy" make sense? Shouldn't it be either "I would recommend this place to my worst enemy" or "I would not even recommend this place to my worst enemy"?

Comment: It's informal, so more common to say "I *wouldn't* recommend this place to my worst enemy", i.e. even my worst enemy doesn't deserve something so bad; *would not* sounds overly emphatic, too formal, or non-fluent. Adding *even* is ok but not necessary nor standard.

Comment: If you want to add "even", you'd prefer, "I would not recommend this place to even my worst enemy". If you say "would not even recommend" that suggests that there are things other than recommending that you might do to your worst enemy, which is not what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! They are helpful to understand. I thought that the meaning of the phrase, "I would not recommend this place to my worst enemy" is unclear as if I were in that situation, either that I would be willing to recommend the place to my worst enemy or that I would not recommend the place even to my worst enemy as it could be too cruel to make one experience the place.

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to illustrate that the place is bad, you would say/write:

> "I would not [even] recommend this place to my worst enemy."

It's understood the same way whether or not you use 'even'. "I would not [even] recommend" is more commonly used than "I would recommend.", but I think any of your proposed phrasing would be understood to mean the same, i.e. that 'this place' is terrible.

The more common phrasing ("I would not recommend") illustrates that the place is so bad that, as much as you dislike the person you dislike most in the world, you would not subject him/her to the experience you had at 'this place'.

If you used the less common phrasing, i.e. that you "would recommend this place to [your] worst enemy", it would likely be understood to mean the same, as I mentioned above. However, it's not clear whether that statement (that you would recommend this place to your worst enemy) is intended to mean that the place is bad, or that you're a nice person and would set differences aside to recommend a good place to your worst enemy.